# Class does not exist Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Al completar y querer guardar un registro de formulario, es decir, al momento de dar clic en el botón guardar me salta el siguiente error:

**Class sisMSP\Http\Requests\PMedicamentosFormRequest does not exist**

No logro entender donde debo agregarle la clase o si debo modificar algo ya digitado.

En el controlador referido al tema tengo lo siguiente:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use sisMSP\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use sisMSP\Http\Requests\PMedicamentosFormRequest;
use sisMSP\App\PMedicamentos;
use DB;

class PMedicamentosController extends Controller
{

 public function store (PMedicamentosFormRequest $request)
    {
        $pmedicamento=new PMedicamentos;
        $pmedicamento->CI=$request->get('CI');
        $pmedicamento->Primer_Nombre=$request->get('Primer_Nombre');
        $pmedicamento->Primer_Apellido=$request->get('Primer_Apellido');
        $pmedicamento->Departamento=$request->get('Departamento');
        $pmedicamento->Medicamento=$request->get('Medicamento');
        $pmedicamento->Prestador_Seguro=$request->get('Prestador_Seguro');
        $pmedicamento->Laboratorio=$request->get('Laboratorio');
        $pmedicamento->N_Sentencia=$request->get('N_Sentencia');
        $pmedicamento->Fecha_Sentencia=$request->get('Fecha_Sentencia');
        $pmedicamento->Tipo_Solicitud=$request->get('Tipo_Solicitud');
        $pmedicamento->Condicion='1';
        $pmedicamento->save();
        return Redirect::to('PMedicamentos');
    }
```

Y en el PMedicamentosFormRequest tengo esto en la parte superior:

```
<?php

namespace SGP\Http\Requests;

use sisMSP\Http\Requests\Request;

class PMedicamentosFormRequest extends Request
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Si debo subir algo mas del código utilizado, favor de decirme

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes mal los namespaces.

***Laravel*** encuentra las clases del sistema, en general, en base a los namespaces.

**Ejemplo de uso de namespaces en Laravel**

Si creamos una carpeta *Zzz* dentro de *app* y dentro la clase *Foo*, su namespace será:

```
namespace App\Zzz;
```

Esta declaración va al principio del fichero que contiene la clase *Foo*, justo después de la apertura del tag de PHP: `<?php`

A la hora de usar la clase *Foo* en otro namespace (diferente de `App\Zzz`) hay que indicarlo de la siguiente manera antes de la definición de esta clase:

```
use App\Zzz\Foo;
```

luego puedes instanciar la clase simplemente así:

```
$foo = new Foo;
```

o así, dentro de la clase directamente, si por ejemplo quieres instanciar la clase *Foo* y no usas la sentencia `use` al principio del fichero:

```
$foo = new \App\Zzz\Foo;
```

En este último caso, se usa la barra inclinada al principio del namespace para indicar que la clase pertenece a un namespace diferente al actual, de otra forma el sistema entendería que la clase se encuentra en: `app/Directorio_de_la_clase_actual/app/Zzz/Foo.php`
y tendrías un trazado de error similar a este:

> Class 'App\Directorio_de_la_clase_actual\App\Zzz/Foo' not found

Comment: Digamos que pude solucionar con tu respuesta pero me salta lo siguiente ahora: **Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequiered does not exist.** Tiene algo que ver con el problema anterior?

Comment: Puede que sí, puede que no. El namespace se usa para que dos clases con el mismo nombre dentro de una app no colisionen, es decir que puedes tener una clase llamada `Validator` con diferentes namespaces. Entonces tienes una clase `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` (el sistema la encuentra), pero no encuentra el método `validateRequiered()` en esa clase, es decir, que puede estar disponible en otra clase `Validator` o no. Mira la doc de https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.class-exists.php y https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.method-exists.php

Comment: Utilize el method-exists y no encontré el metodo validateRequiered() en mi controller, lo debo agregar en la parte de **public function store (PMedicamentosFormRequest $request)** o que otra forma habria para solucionar el error?

Comment: @Laude no puedes usarlo si no ésta. Yo nunca lo he usado, no lo conozco. Hice una búsqueda en una instalación limpia de Laravel 5.8 y no hay resultados: `Searching 8424 files for "function validateRequiered(" 
0 matches`. Tal vez debas plantear una nueva pregunta y explicar que intentas hacer con ese método.

Answer (score 0):

El namespace del Request en mención es:

```
namespace SGP\Http\Requests;
```

por lo cual debes llamarlo de esta manera:

```
use SGP\Http\Requests\PMedicamentosFormRequest;
```

Revisa tus convenciones, y por cierto, es altamente recomendado utilizar siempre `App` como namespace base en Laravel, a menos que tengas un proyecto gigante con servicios e instancias adicionales.

Comment: En el namespace se debe colocar el nombre que tiene la carpeta donde se encuentra todo el proyecto?

Comment: No necesariamente, depende como esté planteado el proyecto.

Comment: Hice lo que me has dicho pero ahora me salta: **Class 'sisMSP\Http\Requests\Request' not found**

Comment: Hay una mezcla bastante rara de namespaces que parecen ser innecesarios. ¿Es acaso tan grande tu proyecto que necesita más de un namespace?

Comment: Ahora acabo de hacer coincidir todos los namespaces a sisMSP y me dice Class 'sisMSP\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found  para ti cuales serian innecesarios? digamos que es un sistema medio respecto a tamaño

Comment: Para que fuera un sistema medio, debería tener al menos conexión con unos dos sistemas externos, unos 10 servicios propios, información en tiempo real y unas 50.000 líneas de código escritas, y unos 20GB en la base de datos. Utiliza un solo namespace para todo el proyecto.